# Nginx SSL get blank page

Tags: nginx, ssl, webserver

I'm trying for hours to put SSL to work on nginx without success. I have already setup all things correct but i'm getting blank page when i trying to access in https. website on http work fine.

I got certificate and key from cloudflare (i already setup with it some time ago and i remember this part).

I have setup the certificate and key on /etc/nginx/ssl and my configuration of server looks like:

```
server {
    listen 443 default default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name myhost.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    root /var/www;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

I got blank page when access on https, and i don't get any erros and logs on erros/access.logs from nginx..

could someone help me?

Comment: What's the response code? 200?

Comment: @anemyte Access to animesflex.com has been deniedYou are not authorized to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403. But i have checked at https://www.digicert.com/help/ and all is fine on my domain.. i don't know what is causing this :/

Comment: 403 is not an SSL problem, although visiting the domain you've mentioned I've got 526, which is an SSL error. It usually means that the certificate is either expired or has been issued to another domain. The configuration in question seems fine so I suggest you double check that the certificate is OK. If you can access the website and get a 403, click the padlock button in the address bar. There is a menu to view the certificate used by the server. That , of course, if you have a response from your server and not cloud flare proxy as I had.

Comment: @anemyte well, try now on animesflex.com

Comment: It seems 403 is cloud flare's response. I see `server: cloudflare` response header. Also add `ssl` to the first `listen` statement: `listen 443 ssl default default_server;`.

Comment: @anemyte I have added ssl like you said but nothings changed.. hope have other thing that need to be adjusted..